# Является ли хорошим тоном программирования следующее?

Tags: c++, code-style

Является ли хорошим тоном программирования не конвертировать один тип в другой?
Например, есть переменная bool m_exist:
Хорошо ли если я пишу следующий код так: `if(m_exist == true)` а не `if(m_exist)`?
Или нет никакой разницы?

Comment: Второй вариант лучше, грамотнее

Comment: А тут вы ничего и не конвертируете - у вас и в том, и в другом случае `bool`. И выражения равнозначны. Как именно писать - зависит от выбранного стиля - команды, если вы в команде, или личных предпочтений.

Comment: Грамотнее `m_exist == true` так как вы четко обозначаете с каким значением сравниваете. Во многих случаях контекст может быть разным и значение не будет очевидно. С точки зрения С, да могут быть проблемы так как распространенная ошибка `m_exist = true`, но это частности.

Comment: Вот тут все разобрано https://habr.com/ru/post/251091/

Comment: Не конвертировать один тип в другой без надобности - это хороший тон, да. Но в приведенном примере, как уже отметили, ничего не конвертируется. А если уж используется явное сравнение `if(m_exist == true)`, то литерал имеет смысл оставлять слева `if(true == m_exist`) для защиты от случайного присвоения.

Comment: @user7860670 [для защиты от случайного присвоения] Нынешние компиляторы стали хитрые и вырабатывают предупреждение в случаях присвоения в условном операторе.

Comment: `#define TRUE FALSE //счастливой отладки`

Comment: @user7860670, кстати такое условие называется «[нотацией Йоды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%99%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B)».

Comment: @becouse искал по `if` и по `true`, но в статье такого нет

Comment: @dlmon см. Lvalue

Comment: @becouse <вы неправильно указали мой ник, поэтому не было уведомления> посмотрел `lvalue`, не советовал бы эту статью, так как в первом же предложении определение `lvalue` неправильное, в комментариях тоже указывают на множество ошибок в статье; правильный ответ у @CrazyElf + зависит от установленного code style; преобразование в `==`, кстати, будет

Answer (score 2):

Наоборот, явное сравнение с `true` использовать почти никогда не нужно. Тем более, в строготипизированных языках типа Си, Си++, C# или Джавы. Сравнение совершенно бесполезное и не добавляет совершенно никакой новой информации. Ну, случай с перегрузкой оператора я не рассматриваю.

Вот в динамически типизированных языках явное сравнение с true может иметь смысл - например, если там может быть другое истинное значение. Но опять же, сравнивать стоит только если ты точно знаешь, что хочешь отделить `true` от других истинных значений, если же ты знаешь, что единственным истинным значением является true, то сравнивать не надо.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю к уже и так отличным комментариям, что в случае булевых функций/переменных хорошим тоном будет правильно назвать функцию/переменную, и тогда вопрос отпадёт почти сам собой. Для большей понятности пусть у нас будет не конкретный даже язык программирования, а некий абстрактный, хотя и C-образный, где точно можно называть всё по-русски. Но эта ситуация легко транслируется и в английский язык для тех, кто хоть сколько-то его понимает.
Итак, два варианта на псевдо-языке. Первый - без явного сравнения.

```
если(файл_существует(имя_файла))
{
    делаем_всякое_с_файлом(имя_файла);
}
```

Всё ведь абсолютно ясно, не правда ли? Просто читаем - и понимаем, что происходит.
Попробуем добавить сравнение:

```
если(файл_существует(имя_файла) == истина)
{
    делаем_всякое_с_файлом(имя_файла);
}
```

Стал ли код **понятнее**? Такое впечатление, что нет. Наоборот - нам теперь надо лишний раз задуматься: что должна выдавать функция `файл_существует`, чтобы выполнилось это условие? Да, через мгновение мы понимаем, что `истину`, но не прямо сразу. А что будет означать ситуация, если условие не выполнилось? А может надо было сравнивать с `ложью`? Опять надо думать. А в первом же варианте думать не надо совсем. Файл существует - заходим в блок кода. Ноль раздумий. Экономия мыслительных мощностей на лицо. Это и есть хороший тон.

Comment: Именно это главная причина не писать явно `== true`. Сравнивать какую-то непонятную булевскую переменную с литералом явно можно, а сравнивать правильно названную (обычно глаголы, начинающиеся с `is_`, `has_` и т.п.) не только не надо, но и ухудшает читаемость